# How to allow other computers from outside my network to access my virtual web server?

Tags: apache-http-server, svn, remote-access

I am working on a project with other people, and we are using my computer as server, we use subversion as a control version, and the repository resides in my computer, we don't want to use any other server, and the problem is that my colleags only have access to the repository when we connected to the same network, how can they access the server (my local server) from outside the network i am conncected to, any suggestion ?

Comment: Do you have access to the router via Telnet, SSH, or WebUI?

Comment: Open the necessary ports on the router that connects your internal network with the internet.

Comment: Why open ports when you can VPN?

Comment: @cricket_007 of course it is. How else can they get internet to the local network? there's always some kind of router involved. If its not the basic home router, he'd know enough to not need to ask this question in the first place, because then you're going higher networking stuff.

Comment: @LPChip The question was more geared towards "that you have access to?" rather than if one is existent.................

Comment: @LPChip - Only asking is OP is like in a company or a school where you would need to talk to a network admin.

Comment: Ah, okay. my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a `VPN` technology so they can access your network from somewhere else in the world or you can simply `setup port forwarding` on your router.

Port Forwarding can be easily achieved using your router menus but your external IP address will often change unless you pay for a static IP address from your ISP.

> Noted: Some ISP routers may have a DynamicDNS (or other service) tab that
>   provides a service to get from the url
>   `myrouternetworkname.dynamicdns.net/` to your ip address. I found this quite cumbersome the first time I did it, but there are guides online to help you with this.

Setting up a VPN may not be ideal, but is often used to play LAN games over the internet so it should fit for any developing needs you have.

Comment: Nice answer. You may add that for VPN, depending on which technology you use, the changing IP may also be a problem.

Comment: Most services will provide IP mapping by default as a basic feature but you are right, your comment should be enough.

Comment: Dynamic DNS to WAN IP + Static IP to LAN machine would be preferred.

Comment: If a service is used, yes. But there are routers out there that are not that expensive that support VPN through PPTP. In these cases port forwarding would still be easier, but for the sake of clarifying if they use such method, the IP changing would still apply. :)